# Why does the RHS of an Exact ODE have to be 0?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

Why is it the case that the RHS of an Exact ODE has to be $0$, rather than an arbitrary function of $x$?

When I can manipulate an ODE into (where $y = y(x)$, as usual) $\frac{∂F(x,\ y)}{∂x} + \frac{∂F(x,\ y)}{∂y}y′ = g(x)$, since the LHS is $\frac{d}{dx}F(x,\ y)$, why can't I then just write the implicit solution $F(x,\ y) = G(x) + C$?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3086303/why-do-exact-differential-equations-have-to-equal-zero) appears to address what I'm asking, but it only convinces me that *if* $g(x) = 0$, *then* we can view the solutions as the level curves of $F(x,\ y)$, not that the anticedent must hold in order to solve the ODE.  What algebraic or calculus rule is being violated by my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you define a new function $\tilde F(x,y)-G(x)$ and get to solve $\tilde F(x,y)=C$.

Nobody prevents you to write
$$
M(x,y)\,dx+N(x,y)\,dy=g(x)\,dx
$$
which you can again normalize to 
$$
(M(x,y)-g(x))\,dx+N(x,y)\,dy=0
$$
If $(M,N)$ is exact, then also $(M-g,N)$ is exact, so that there is no added difficulty.